How to solve Error 1002 "Unauthorized" HTX API?
An error occurs when trying to retrieve data from the HTX API endpoint. I checked the keys. I checked the time, it is indicated in the same format as in the documentation. In the documentation the endpoint is the same
const axios = require('axios');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require('fs');

const API_KEY = 'tets';  
const API_SECRET = 'test';  
const BASE_URL = 'https://api.huobi.pro';

function generateSignature(method, requestPath, body, timestamp) {
    if (typeof body === 'object' && Object.keys(body).length === 0) {
        body = '';
    } else if (typeof body === 'string') {
        body = body;
    } else {
        body = JSON.stringify(body);
    }

    const message = `${timestamp}${method.toUpperCase()}${requestPath}${body}`;
    console.log('Message for signature:', message);
    const signature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', API_SECRET).update(message).digest('base64');
    return signature;
}

async function getWithdrawQuota(currency) {
    const method = 'GET';
    const requestPath = `/v2/account/withdraw/quota?currency=${currency}`;
    const body = '';

    try {
        const timestamp = new Date().toISOString(); 
        const signature = generateSignature(method, requestPath, body, timestamp);
        console.log('Timestamp:', timestamp);
        console.log('Signature:', signature);
        console.log('Request Path:', requestPath);

        const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}${requestPath}`, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-Huobi-API-Key': API_KEY,
                'X-Huobi-Signature': signature,
                'X-Huobi-Timestamp': timestamp,
            },
        });

        console.log('Response:', response.data);

        if (response.data.code !== 200) {
            throw new Error(`API error: ${response.data.message}`);
        }

        const filteredData = {};
        const chains = response.data.data.chains;

        if (!chains) {
            throw new Error('No chains data found.');
        }

        chains.forEach(chain => {
            const chainName = chain.chain;

            if (!filteredData[chainName]) {
                filteredData[chainName] = {
                    maxWithdrawAmt: chain.maxWithdrawAmt,
                    withdrawQuotaPerDay: chain.withdrawQuotaPerDay,
                    remainWithdrawQuotaPerDay: chain.remainWithdrawQuotaPerDay,
                    withdrawQuotaPerYear: chain.withdrawQuotaPerYear,
                    remainWithdrawQuotaPerYear: chain.remainWithdrawQuotaPerYear,
                    withdrawQuotaTotal: chain.withdrawQuotaTotal,
                    remainWithdrawQuotaTotal: chain.remainWithdrawQuotaTotal,
                };
            }
        });

        fs.writeFileSync('withdraw_quota_data.json', JSON.stringify(filteredData, null, 2), 'utf-8');

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error withdraw quota:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
    }
}

getWithdrawQuota('usdt'); 

There is a similar question, but it didn't solve my problem

HTX / Huobi error api-signature-not-valid

Console output:
Message for signature: 2024-12-18T21:46:09.511ZGET/v2/account/withdraw/quota?currency=usdt
Timestamp: 2024-12-18T21:46:09.511Z
Signature: hIaoWIW/KASx2B9brEdoibewRgvJGZx16R4uL58Clxs=
Request Path: /v2/account/withdraw/quota?currency=usdt
Response: { code: 1002, message: 'unauthorized' }
Error fetching withdraw quota: API Error: unauthorized

